# operator<< overload in C++ not working as expected

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have defined a class template `MyVector` and overloaded the `operator<<` to print the vector that it holds.

```
//MyVector definition
template<int n, typename T>
class MyVector{


  private:
    vector<T> vetor;
  public:
    //Several Methods
    MyVector operator+(MyVector& v){
        //Adds 2 vectors
    }

   template<typename U, int m>
   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& o, MyVector<m,U>& v);
};

template<typename T, int n>
ostream& operator << (ostream& o, MyVector<n,T> &v){
  o << "[";
  for(auto itr = v.vetor.begin(); itr != v.vetor.end()-1; ++itr){
    o << *itr <<", ";
  }
  o << v.vetor.back() << "]";
  return o;
}
```

The operator seems to work fine for simple use cases, but when adding 2 instances of `MyVector`, the `operator<<` throws an:

```
invalid operands to binary expression
```

```
int main(){
  MyVector<2,int> v1;
  MyVector<2,int> v2;
  MyVector<2,int> v3;

  v1.add(1,2);
  v2.add(3,4);
  v3 = v1+v2;

  cout << v3 << endl;  // --> This prints "[7,11]" to the console
  cout << v1+v2 << endl; // --> This throws the exception
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should pass parameter as lvalue reference only when you have intention to modify it. In any other case either pass by value or const reference (to avoid expensive copying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator+` on `MyVector` returns a temporary:

```
   MyVector operator+(MyVector& v);
// ^^^^^^^^ temporary
```

which can't bind to a non-const reference which `operator<<` expects:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& o, MyVector<m,U>& v);
                               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  non-const reference
```

You can fix this by accepting a const reference instead:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& o, MyVector<m,U> const & v);
                                             // ^^^^^
```

---

Similarly, your `operator+` should take it's argument by const reference, and also should be const-qualified:

```
MyVector operator+(MyVector const & v) const;
                         // ^^^^^      ^^^^^
```

to allow expressions like this to work:

```
MyVector<2, int> const v = // ...
std::cout << v + v + v;
```

Comment: `operator+` parameter should be also `const` reference to prevent next question, why `a + b + c` does not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That was very helpful, I'm quite new to C++ and I still struggle a bit to understand those "const" parameters.

Comment: No problem :) Consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.